# Android retain AsyncTask state/progress

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In the app I'm developing atm. I use asynctasks to upload videos to a website, as it stands now if the application process is killed (User returning to home screen using the back key), those asynctasks are lost. ideally I would want the uploads to carry on despite the application process being killed, but I don't think that is possible.

I wonder if there is a way to retain their progress somehow (Maybe support from the website API is necessary?), or if not at least save the details of the asynctask and restart it when the app is opened again.

Vimeos application seems to have been able to resume video uploads, even after having killed the application process, thats exactly what I'm hoping to achieve.

Appreciate any ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may be using the wrong architecture.

Anything that needs to survive in between Activity transitions is more suited for a Service. A service runs in the background (possibly even after the app is closed) and lets you do long running things such as performing uploads.

To kill the app process but have the Service continue to run, you can assign the service to a separate Android process using android:process in the manifest.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#proc

See this thread too:
[How to keep a service running in background even after user quits the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434179/how-to-keep-a-service-running-in-background-even-after-user-quits-the-app)