# Return START_STICKY from Service with Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

I made a `Service` that uses a `Thread` when it is started. I want to keep the service running when my application is closed (`START_STICKY`).

To make the service keep running, I have to return `START_STICKY`:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
     new Thread( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
              try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

**How can I return it with my thread?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434179/how-to-keep-a-service-running-in-background-even-after-user-quits-the-app

Comment: I know that I have to use START_STICKY but how can I return it if I have a thread onStartCommand?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a misunderstanding of the concept of [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html). The thread you've started in `onStartCommand()` does not "prevent" the method from returning. What happens here is as follows:

1. `onStartCommand()` is called on some thread (likely the main one)
2. `Thread.start()` returns immediately followed by returning from `onStartCommand()` with `START_STICKY` flag.

As a result there are at least two threads running, the one on which `onStartCommand()` has been invoked, the other one that performs the `run()` method.